# Load image into picturebox only when needed/visible

Tags: c#, image, scroll, picturebox, groupbox

I'm programming a little application that shows thumbnails of images. All the displayed images are in the same directory, each Image is inside it's own groupbox with a few labels and a checkbox. All the group boxes get added to a flowlayoutpanel. The problem is, that the amount of images may get pretty large and I'm concerned that memory usage / performance might get a little out of hand if I load all images even if they're not yet visible.

Is there a way to load only images that are currently visible to the user? My first thought is  storing the location of my boxes and determine which images to load depending on the scroll position, or is there an easier way to determine if a picturebox/groupbox is currently visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally what you should be doing is creating buffer logic rather than hiding 1 image and showing the other. It's a much better idea to have a couple buffers loading the images before you show them and have a fixed number of actual fields showing images rather than a new set per image.

But if your solution requires that, try to create a custom user control.

Try something like this:

```
public class customUserControl : UserControl
{
    //Store image as a Uri rather than an Image
    private Uri StoredImagePath;
    public class PictureBoxAdv : PictureBox
    {
        public PictureBoxAdv()
        {
            this.VisibleChanged +=new EventHandler(VisibleChanged);
        }
    }
    public Uri Image
    {
        get { return StoredImagePath; }
        set
        {
            StoredImagePath = value;
            if (this.Visible && StoredImagePath != null)
            {
                this.Image = Image.FromFile(StoredImagePath.AbsolutePath);
            }
        }
    }
    public void VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When becomes visible, restore image, invisible, nullify.
        if (this.Visible && StoredImagePath != null)
        {
            this.Image = Image.FromFile(StoredImagePath.AbsolutePath);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Image = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you mean is: Have a set amount of boxes visible and change the images displayed in these boxes? I currently have a List with all image filenames. I could basically take a scrollbar and set the min/max values to whatever amount of images i have and swap out the currently displayed images. What I don't understand is the buffer logic, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: The buffering logic is simple, simply store all the images in a List<Uri> object and when you want to call a specific image to replace another one, simply call imageBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(uiList[2].AbsolutePath); 

If you want, you could have additional Images that are used to swap with the current ones, so that way you can load in the images in the background and once they are loaded, just them to the PictureBox you want to replace.

Comment: Aha, that's basically what I did anyway. I ended up putting 6 groupboxes and a scrollbar onto the form. I stored all the my image paths in a list and the scrollbar value determines what images are displayed. The image display part is handled in a separate thread. 
Thanks for the help!